# How do I rotate and resize a canvas, while maintaining rotated aspect ratio, and resizing height?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm using phonegap, which is relatively unimportant to the question. When I take a vertical image, using `capture.captureImage`, it comes back horizontal.

Anyways, I want to rotate the image vertically, like it was when I took the photo, expanding to the top and bottom of a newly created thumbnail that is 160px wide and 90px high *(16:9)*. I want to maintain its flipped aspect ratio *(like it was when I took the pic)* of 9:16 within the 16:9 taking up the entire height of the 90px high thumb.

Below I am showing the `img`, although the code won't work unless you change the `id='captured_img'` Element to a local URL, due to external image `src` security problems with `canvas.toDataURL()`. So `<img width='160' height='90' id='captured_img' src='mustBeLocal.png' />`. If you want you can just right click and save the `img` I provided.

If you run the tests, you will see that `horizontal` works fine. For reasons unknown to me, however, the `vertical` test shows an image that appears smaller that its shown dimensions.

If you can point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

```js
var doc, M, I;
onload = function(){ // make sure DOM is loaded
doc = document;
M = function(tag){
  return doc.createElement(tag);
}
I = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
var captured_img = I('captured_img'), canvas = M('canvas'), ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'), horizontal = I('horizontal'), vertical = I('vertical');
var output_img = I('output_img');
function reuse(force){ // just using force because you're not on your phone
  var iw = captured_img.width, ih = captured_img.height, w, h, hw = 0, hh = 0, s;
  if(force || innerWidth < innerHeight){
    h = 50.625*iw/ih; w = h*ih/iw; s = true;
  }
  else{
    w = 160; h = w*ih/iw;
  }
  canvas.width = w; canvas.height = h;
  console.log(w+'--'+h); // width and height are showing correctly
  // formula was also tested using a 400 x 300 image and aspect results look good to me - 4:3 90px high
  if(s){
    hw = w/2; hh = h/2; ctx.translate(hw, hh); ctx.rotate(Math.PI/2);
  }
  ctx.drawImage(captured_img, -hw, -hh, w, h);
  output_img.src = canvas.toDataURL(); ctx.restore();
}
horizontal.onclick = function(){
  reuse();
}
vertical.onclick = function(){
  reuse(true);
}
}// end load
```

```css
#container{
  width:160px; height:90px; background:#000; text-align:center;
}
#output_img{
  vertical-align:middle;
}
#captured_img,#container{
  border:1px solid gold;
}
input[type=button]{
  margin-top:5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='description' content='Test Page' /><meta name='keywords' content='test page, test template' />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0' />
    <title>Test Template</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>  
    <h2>160 x 90 - 16:9 aspect ratio</h2>
    <img width='160' height='90' id='captured_img' src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZQLy.png' alt='needs to be a local URL' />
  
    <hr />
    
    <div id='container'><img id='output_img' /></div>
    <input id='horizontal' type='button' value='horizontal' />
    <input id='vertical' type='button' value='vertical' />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

There's really no security error when you use a local URL. Just save my image and test on XAMPP or WAMP. Code and image are perfectly safe.

Comment: when I click the 'horizontal' or 'vertical' buttons in your snippet, I get a runtime error.

Comment: Thanks for checking out my question. Hopefully you will read it more carefully. Oh, I also had to update some of the code. It's working on my localhost with a local image, just not the way I want.

Comment: Sorry, I had just skimmed it. Afraid I don't have time to debug locally right now. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

After a bunch of random trial by error testing, I have concluded my `reuse` function should look like:

```js
function reuse(force){ // just using force because you're not on your phone
  var iw = captured_img.width, ih = captured_img.height, w, h, hw, hh, s;
  if(force || innerWidth < innerHeight){
    iw = ih; ih = captured_img.width; s = true;
  }
  if(iw/ih < 16/9){
    h = 90; w = h*iw/ih;
  }
  else{
    w = 160; h = w*ih/iw;
  }
  canvas.width = w; canvas.height = h;
  if(s){
    hw = w/2; hh = h/2; ctx.save(); ctx.translate(hw, hh); ctx.rotate(Math.PI/2); ctx.drawImage(captured_img, -hh, -hw, h, w); ctx.restore();
  }
  else{
    ctx.drawImage(captured_img, 0, 0, w, h);
  }
  output_img.src = canvas.toDataURL();
}
```

It drove me crazy. Hopefully this will help anyone with the same problem.

PS

If you want anything to fit into any aspect ratio, all you would need to do is change the `w` and `h` `var`s to match your width and height of your preferred aspect and make sure you change out that `16/9` with your `w/h`.